# null. empty, white space string in java

Tags: java, string, null, whitespace

In the following code:

```
import java.util.*; 
 public class test{     
     public static void main(String[] args){             
         System.out.println("".length());     
     }
 }
```

the output is 0.

but in the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st = stdin.next();
        System.out.println(st.length());
        System.out.println(st.equals(""));
    }
}
```

when I enter "" or an empty string, the outputs are:

```
2
false
```

I changed `std.next()` to `std.nextLine()` but the output was the same.

When I change `System.out.println(st.equals(""));` to `System.out.println(st.equals(" "));` 
and I enter " " or space the outputs are:

```
1
false
```

Why is that?

Comment: Consider `newline` (enter). try `st.trim().length()` and `st.trim().equals("")`.

Comment: you confuse java string with the input string

Answer (score 0):

The input `""` is two characters that's why you get length 2 and `""` is *not equal to* an empty string. As for the second case when you input `" "` you're getting length 1 because `String::next()` can read user input only till the space. It cannot read two words separated by a space and once again that is *not equal to* an empty string. To conclude you cannot enter an empty string when using `String::next()`, not even a string that's filled with whitespaces. You'll need to use `String::nextLine()` for that.

When it comes to reading user input we don't represent empty strings as `""`. *An empty string is a string which has a length of zero*.